# How to count total number using if statement

Tags: python-3.x

This is a tutorial question:
Use these lists in nested loops to find out which students are enrolled in both classes and count the
total number of students. Your output should look like the following:

Student: Audrey is enrolled in both classes
Student: Ben is enrolled in both classes
Student: Julia is enrolled in both classes
Student: Paul is enrolled in both classes
Student: Sue is enrolled in both classes
Student: Mark is enrolled in both classes
6 students are enrolled in Computer Science and Maths

I have tried count, split (was desperate) and other ways to try and get it to count how many students but having no luck. Can someone please suggest a way to get this or direct me to the correct section in the documentation?

```
for i in mathStudents:
    both = ""
    #ele = 0
    for i in csStudents:
        if i in mathStudents and i in csStudents:
            both = i
            #ele +=1

            print("Student: ", both, "is enrolled in both classes \n there is", #ele.count(i) 
            )

    break
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would just be lazy and use `set()`:

```
print("Total number is: ", len(set(mathStudents) | set(csStudents))
```

If you want to use for loops to get the total number:

```
both = 0
for x in mathStudents: #don't use the same variable for each loop
    for y in csStudents: #they overwrite each other
        if x == y: #same student
            both +=1 #both is increased
            print(x, "is in both classes")

total_students = len(mathStudents) + len(csStudents) - both #total = math + cs - overlap
print(total_students)
```